# Windows 8 restarts while locked

Tags: windows-8, crash, reboot

Here are the symptoms. The PC restarts overnight with no obvious reason. It's not because of power outages as the nearby PCs don't have the issue and some are plugged in the same outlet. It never happens when the machine is not locked. I disabled auto lock and left it that way overnight with a screen recorder on (who knows?), it didn't restart. Moreover, as soon as I locked the machine after that, it restarted while I was away for a few minutes. There are no relevant reboot events in Event Viewer, it's as if it's caused by a kernel failure or hardware reset. This is very annoying as I frequently need to run unattended time consuming tasks overnight.

Comment: Check if there's a task with event: on lock. But otherwise, there really should be an event in the eventlog.

Comment: I can find no scheduled task of such type. Last event ID 6006 is from 6 days ago and it did reboot last evening. There is a 6005 event at ~8AM today but that doesn't tell me anything. How can Windows log events in case of a severe crash (like drivers etc)?

Comment: Either you will find: Windows rebooted with reason xxxx initiated by xxxx, or you get: Windows restarted unexpectedly. See C:\....\minidump.dmp for the crash report.

Comment: There are no recent events with ID 1074 (I guess that's what you mean). The minidump is from a few days ago.

Comment: There are different ID's for restarts. I don't know all of them, so you better trigger the restart, then check both the application log and system log for all entries that occur around that specific time.